# How to add class dynamically in angular 4

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-components

I'm working on a project using angular 4, How do I add class to the body of index.html only. for example

```
   <body class="home">
      <app-root></app-root>

   </body>
```

I want this class to be added only when my HomeComponent load and remove for any other pages/component

Cheers to everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really use Angular features in the index.html. I would suggest a different approach to the structure of your application.

Define your `app-root` component to only be a `router-outlet`. Then build a shell component with your menu, header, and any other styles you want for your "home".

You can then route any pages you want without the styles directly into the app-root's router-outlet and any pages you want with your style to the shell component.

I have an example set up this way here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**shell.component.html**

```
<mh-menu></mh-menu>

<div class='container'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```